# Implement a function

Tags: python

Implement a function punctuation() that takes no parameters, inputs a string from the user, and prints all of the punctuation characters appearing in the string, in order from left to right.

```
def punctuation():

    a = raw_input("Please enter a string:")

    check = ['!', ',', '.', ':', '?', ';']
    for p in check:
        if p in a:
            a.remove(p)
```

I keep getting an error sign on IDLE that raw_input isn't defined? Then also, I'm not too familiar what the split() is supposed to do? Be gentle guys, I'm a python n00b.

Comment: The phrasing sounds like this is a homework question. If so, please apply the `homework` tag and/or mention it. IF not, forgive my misinterpretation.

Comment: I don't see a `split()` in your code, but the docs are right here: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Comment: I meant the split() function in general. Sorry I should've been more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to do it the reverse way as far as your logic is concerned.

1. Maintain a list (or string of) punctuation characters. (Check if the standard library module string has any help here)
2. Go through each character of your input string and if it is present in the list above, print it.

Looks like `string` module can ofcourse be of help here:

```
>>> import string
>>> string.punctuation
'!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'
```

So, you will write your program something along the lines:

```
for each_character in mystr:
    if each_character in string.punctuation:
```

Yeah, you can use `raw_input()` in python2 to get the string like you are getting. For python3, you should just use `input()`

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are using Python 3.  `raw_input()` has been replaced with `input()`

Comment: I've done so. Now I get this error. "'str' object has no attribute 'remove'"

Comment: Python strings are immutable. That is, you cannot remove characters from one. A better solution might be to build up a list of the punctuation characters, and then print that.

Comment: BTW you can turn an immutable string into mutable list using `[x for x in the_string]` and a list to string by `"".join(the_list)`.